# Calculus - Derivative help.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to get dervative for this function

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}'$$

I used $(f+g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$ so:

$$\sqrt{1} + \sqrt {\sqrt{x}}$$

So :

$$\sqrt{1}' = 1' = 0$$

$$\sqrt {\sqrt{x}'} = \sqrt {\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}}'$$

Define :  $f(x) = \sqrt{x} , g(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

Then using the chain law with f and g :

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}} * \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Therefore the answer is :

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}' = 0 + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}} * \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Although the book answer is : $$\frac{1}{4 \sqrt {x+x \sqrt{x}}}$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $f(y) = \sqrt{y}$ and $g(x) = 1+\sqrt{x}$ and then follows $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: So, in your humble opinion, $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt a+\sqrt b$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some little problems here. First, $(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$ means that, for example, $(\sin x + \cos x)' = (\sin x)' + (\cos x)'$; you cannot do this with your function because you are not dealing with a function that is the sum of two other functions, but with a *composistion* of different functions.

Hence, you have to use this other rule: $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$, where $g(x)$ is $1 + \sqrt{x}$, and $f(x)$ is $\sqrt{x}$; in fact, $f(g(x))$ is indeed $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}$. Now, using that rule you see that the derivative is:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}} \cdot (1 + \sqrt{x})' =$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}} \cdot [1' + (\sqrt{x})'] =$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} =$$
$$\frac{1}{4(\sqrt{x + x\sqrt{x}})}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Is $\displaystyle (a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ for all $a,b??$

Using Chain Rule,
$$\frac{d[(1+\sqrt x)^{-\frac12}]}{dx}=\frac{d[(1+\sqrt x)^{-\frac12}]}{d(1+\sqrt x)}\frac{d(1+\sqrt x)}{dx}$$